# apply function and series object

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I want to use the `apply` function to sort each row of a dataframe `df`:

```
ID   Student1    Student2    Student3  
1    A           B           C
2    M           E           F
3    H           A           D
```

The code is

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[1, 'A', 'B', 'C'], [2, 'M', 'E', 'F'], [3, 'H', 'A', 'D']]), columns=['ID', 'Student1', 'Student2', 'Student3'])
df1 = df.apply(np.sort, axis = 1)
```

`df1` is a dataframe, not a series object. It looks like this:

```
ID   Student1    Student2    Student3  
1    A           B           C
2    E           F           M
3    A           D           H
```

How can I get a dataframe of the following? Thanks.

```
ID      
1   [A, B, C]     
2   [E, F, M]
3   [A, D, H]
```

Comment: Also if your question been answered by blow , please selected one of them as accept thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `np.sort` ***without*** using `apply` , check : [When should I ever want to use pandas apply() in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

```
import numpy as np 
df.iloc[:,1:]=np.sort(df.iloc[:,1:].values,1)
df
Out[463]: 
   ID Student1 Student2 Student3
0   1        A        B        C
1   2        E        F        M
2   3        A        D        H
```

Then

```
s = pd.Series(df.iloc[:,1:].values.tolist(),index=df.ID)
s
Out[466]: 
ID
1    [A, B, C]
2    [E, F, M]
3    [A, D, H]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

This works like a charm:

```
df.set_index(['ID']).agg(list,axis=1).reset_index()
```